# how activate autocompletion in Spyder

Tags: spyder

despite all flags in Tools-->Completion & Lights-->General are set to "on", editor completion wont work anyway.. neighter `TAB` nor `Ctrl+Space` activate the function.. system characteristics: Spyder 5.1.5|Python 3.9.7 64-bit | Qt 5.12.10 | PyQt5 5.12.3 | Windows 10. Any advise,plz ?

thks

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html?highlight=pip#troubleshooting-completion

Comment: I  have the same problem, installed spyder 5.1.5 from within ArcPro and autocompletion does not work. I have tried restarting the LSP as suggested by link but the icon just ends up spinning around forever. Did you find a solution?